# bigquery query or ddl statement to both create_if_needed and write_append

Tags: google-bigquery

For programmatic reasons, I would like to issue the same DDL statement twice:

```
    INSERT INTO dataset.tabledest(id, vi)
    SELECT 'test' AS id,
      'value' AS vi
    FROM dataset.tablesource
```

- The first time it is called, I would like it to create the table if it does not exist and append the results of the query
- The second time it is called, I would like it to append the results

Using the BigQuery API, this can be done by:

- use the select statement only as the query
- set the destination table as a parameter (eg. using the R bigrquery API, `, destination_table='...',`)
- set `write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND'`
- set `create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED'`

I'm unsure if this can be accomplished via a single query that does not require additional external parameters passed to the API.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way using **single** query, while it can be done with a script by checking table existence from information_schema.

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'tabledest') THEN
  CREATE TABLE dataset.tabledest (...);
END IF;

INSERT dataset.tabledest SELECT ...
```

(Reminded by the other answer) Alternatively, you can do:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataset.tabledest (...);
INSERT dataset.tabledest SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As @yun-zhang mentioned doing it in a single statement might not be possible.

Alternatively, you can also use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS... in place of checking occurrence of table in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.